# Racket program not working as it should

Tags: scheme, racket

i made a function which takes a list and two elements of the list. It should return #t if the second argument appears in the list argument before the third argument:

The procedure should also return #f if either of the supposed elements doesn't appear at all.

here is what I got so far:

```
(define (before-in-list? lst a b )
  (cond
  ((empty? lst ) #f)
  ((eq? (car lst ) a) ( map b (cdr lst)) #t)
  ((eq? (car lst ) b) #f)
  (else (before-in-list? (cdr lst ) a b ))))
```

to test it, i used:

```
 (before-in-list? '(back in the ussr) '(in) '(ussr))
 (before-in-list? '(back in the ussr) '(the) '(ussr))
```

the problem is that it gives me f every time.

any tips on how to fix it please?

Answer (score 1):

The way you're using `map` doesn't make sense. Also, you should use `equal?` for more general comparisons, and the `a` and `b` parameters should not be lists. Try this:

```
(define (before-in-list? lst a b)
  (cond
    ((empty? lst ) #f)
    ((equal? (car lst) a)
     (if (member b (cdr lst)) #t #f))
    ((equal? (car lst) b) #f)
    (else (before-in-list? (cdr lst ) a b))))

(before-in-list? '(back in the ussr) 'in 'ussr)
=> #t
(before-in-list? '(back in the ussr) 'the 'ussr)
=> #t
```

Comment: @yousifS no problem! If this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the check mark to its left ;)

Comment: @yousifS please, don't forget to accept this answer!